# How to place a menu in bottom area?

Tags: html, css

i have this site:

http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/

I want to move the menu in the bottom area of container as in the picture below

http://i61.tinypic.com/33w4caq.jpg

This code CSS for the menu:

```
.main-navigation {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}
```

I tried to do that `position:absolute; bottom:0px;` but not working.

I found some example here on the site and I managed to implement

Can I get down menu `margin-top: X value` but no other method?

Can you help me to solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you make a JSfiddle illustrating the problem you're having, it's easier to troubleshoot and fix errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When ever you give `position:absolute` to an element it is positioned to nearest parent having  position  or `body` if no parent is positioned. It is safe to use `position:relative` on the parent of element you are trying to give `position:absolute`.

So in the code below I am giving `position:relative` to the parent of element you are trying to position.So that required element is positioned relative to .site-header.

I hope this helps you in long run.

```
.site-header{
  position:relative;
 }

#site-navigation{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: @user1789573 If you make a fiddle, or try it in Chrome dev tools, you'll see that roshan is correct.

Comment: @user1789573 If an answer is wrong, explain how or don't comment. Saying "This won't work...you're wrong." Isn't constructive or helpful by any means.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `padding-top`, for example

```
.main-navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

`inline-block` is unnecessary

Answer (score -4):

Simply put your HTML code snippet at the bottom of your HTML document.

Comment: This is the best and easiest solution.

Comment: I suspect you are being downvoted primarily because of your comments, not because of your attempt at a solution. *Keep the solutions coming, but keep the comments respectful - we all are learning/improving through this method.*

Comment: Not really. Just don't apply CSS to that particular code snippet. Done!

Comment: Okay, let's see it - show us your solution with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), or at least with some code. There is not so much markup that it cannot be reproduced in a couple of minutes. *(I agree, that should be the OP's job, but we all get this privilege from time to time...)* Remember, too, that the page will grow as OP continues development. I suspect you will find that roshan's solution is best -- but I look forward to your solution example.